# Devise/Facebook callback NoMethodError (undefined method `name=' for #<User:0x007

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I am trying to integrate omniauth-facebook into my web site but I keep getting the following err (or something similar) on callback:

NoMethodError (undefined method `name=' for #<User:0x007f507c6f9158>):
 app/models/user.rb:14:in`block in find_for_facebook_oauth'
 app/models/user.rb:9:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
 app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in`facebook'

Here is my user.rb:

```
     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
             :confirmable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

      def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
          where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
            user.provider = auth.provider
            user.uid = auth.uid
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            user.name = auth.info.name   
            user.image = auth.info.image 
          end
      end

    end
```

Not sure why it is complaining about procedure "name" - shouldn't it be looking for a field ? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `undefined method name=' for #<User:0x007f507c6f9158>` error on

```
user.name = auth.info.name
```

It just means that you *don't have a field* named `name` in `users` table. So, the **setter method `name=`** (Note `=` at the end of method name) does not exist in the `User` model.

If you are planning to use `name` field on `users` then add it in the `users` table.

- Create a migration file for adding `name` field in `users` table by following command

  ```
  rails generate migration AddNameToUsers name:string
  ```
- Run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: I added the name field with the migration but I'm still getting the same error. I do a heroku run more db/schema.rb and the name field doesn't show. I do heroku pg:reset DATABASE and a heroku run rake db:migrate and it produces an error - PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "name" of relation "users" already exists.

Comment: Restart the server after adding the field in database then check whether or not you get error. Let me know.

Comment: I did a heroku restart and looks like its still not there - and when I try the Facebook link (users/auth/facebook) it routes me to the sign_in instead :(

Comment: Ooops - I just did a 'normal' sign_up, confirmed via email, and was able to login with Facebook - no callback problem - in other words the normal flow of modern software development.. Thank again.